# Notation for $n$-dimensional intervals

Tags: notation

I have a function that maps a number of reals to points where each of its dimensions is constrained to the same interval.  I thought about writing it like so:

$$f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow (a,b)^n$$

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? It coincides with the notion of [Cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_power) which is commonly used.

Comment: Just wondering because I haven't seen an example of that before and I don't write math often.

Comment: I go often with a sequences of $n$ zeroes and ones and I'm denoting it as elements of $\{0, 1\}^n$. It is surely common. (Unless you're dealing simultaneously with a dot product of $a$ and $b$ and denoting it $(a, b)$, you wouldn't face a confusion.)

Comment: Though if the "vocabulary" of the notions in your article grows valuable, you may think of a section devoted to it.